# the string length of jq output is wrong, and it is impossible to compare

Tags: string, bash, compare, jq, carriage-return

i dont get this problem... maybe someone can help me out :)

i have a Jsonfile and i read out strings and put it into variables. if i compare these after the loop they never are the same.. the outputs of jq have a hidden charakter or so..

Examplecode:

```
while read -r id
do      
    read -r hostname
    for server in "$serverlist"
    do
        if [[ "$hostname" == "$server" ]]; then
            echo "$hostname"
            echo "$server"
        else
            errorser[$i]=$server
            i=$((i+1))
        fi
    done
done < <(jq -r '.[] | .id, .serverinfos.hostname | @text' $jsonlist)
```

serverlist is a array with strings of hostnames like "flowmox".
If i do a simple size on the string which came out if the jq it shows for the text "flowmox" 8 but it is 7...
cutting is also not possible

```
        echo size=${#hostname} 
        hostname="${hostname##*( )}"
        echo size=${#hostname}
        echo size="flowmox"
```

Result:

```
8
8
7
```

added part of the jsonfile:

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "childofid":null,
    "parentofids":[null],
    "infosupdatedat":"2021-11-27",
    "serverinfos":{
        "hostname":"flowmox",
        "description":"Proxmox - Host for vm's and more",
        "status":"ready",
        "servertype":"physisch",
        "category":"vm-host",
        "productname":"ProLiant DL380 G7",
        "Model":"589150-421",
        "Serialnumber":"",
        "managementtype":"ILO3"
    },
```

.
.
.

Comment: Add example input

Comment: Maybe an extra linefeed at the end? Anyway you can pipe your script into `cat -A` to identify the extra character. It outputs `\n` as `$` and most other control characters as their caret notation, e.g. `^M` for `\r`

Comment: i didnt add the json cause  it is to big... but i can add a part of it..

in my opinion the json file has no value gain to solve this problem ;) as i said its "flowmox" everywhere. 

thanks @Aaron i try that

Comment: thanks @Aaron cat -A shows the problem ... the output of jq is "flowmox^M$" and not "flowmox" ...
andy idea how i can get rid of that? Thanks.

Comment: your input must be a windows-formatted file, where lines end in `\r\n` instead of `\n`. You can convert your file's linefeeds to unix style by using `dos2unix yourFile` or `tr -d $'\r'`

Answer (score 0):

This seems a behavior of jq with the raw output. each result is in a new line.

read here:
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/787

Actually, in 1.5 it's already the case that you can use -j to stop newlines being printed, but it does put jq into raw-output mode.

unfortunately it doesnt solve the problem for me. i need to cut the last charakter out...

maybe "hostname=`echo $hostname | tr -d '\n'`" is a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

If the `dos2unix` utility is available, you can use the following :

```
dos2unix $jsonList # or dos2unix -o "$jsonList" on some versions
while read -r id; do
    #[...]
done < <(jq -r '.[] | .id, .serverinfos.hostname | @text' "$jsonlist")
```

Otherwise you can loop over each file of `$jsonList` to remove `\r`s with `tr`:

```
for file in "$jsonList"; do
    tr -d $'\r' > "${file}.new" < "${file}"
    mv "${file.new}" "${file}"
done
while read -r id; do
    #[...]
done < <(jq -r '.[] | .id, .serverinfos.hostname | @text' "$jsonlist")
```